# visible and invisible Button when click + the same for scrolling in ScrollView ios

Tags: ios, uibutton, scrollview

I have 2 buttons known as `previousBttn` and `nextBttn` for `scrollView`. I have 3 images in `scrollView`.

1. I want to hide `previousBttn` like this: [...] >  at the first image
2. When I click on `nextBttn` to second image, 2 button will show like this: < [...] >
3. The end, at third image the `nextBttn` will hide and previousBttn will show like this: < [...]

   Process:
   [...] >  < [...] >   < [...]

And also it is the same when we `swipe` all images.

Comment: each image width in scrollview?

Comment: you can implement you own logic for this one because we don't know what you want exactly.

Comment: Yes and it works when we click on the previou or next button to go the  another image.

Comment: contentOffset += imageView_.frame.size.width;
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentOffset, scrollView.frame.size.height); the value of contentOffset will change in loop.

Comment: Yes it is, i use loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do it your own. you know the index of the current visible page and total images count. if (index == 0) hidePreviousButtonORShowThis[...]>. else if (index == totalImageCount - 1) then hideNextButton else UnhideBothButtons.

you can use image for these signs [...]> <[...] <[...]>

Answer (score 0):

```
    int currentIndex = 0;   // set to first postion
    // if you are at first position
    if(currentIndex == 0)
    {
        // hide previous button
    }
    else if(currentIndex == yourImageCount)
    {
        // hide next button
    }
    else
    {
        // show both the buttons
    }
```